# Can't load shared library, even though it is in the right path

Tags: shared-libraries

i'm trying to run a kinect using a raspberry pi model 3 b.
To do this i installed OpenNI, SensorKinect and NITE using this guide

http://www.etti.tuiasi.ro/cin/Courses/SistEmbedded/Projects/Linux/BeagleBoard/Kinect_on_Ubuntu/Kinect_on_Ubuntu.html

Then when i tried to run the code i got the error

```
Can't create any node of the requested type!
```

From what i could gather this is a problem with NITE, so i tried using the sample code provided with the NITE installation, which said it couldn't find the library

```
libXnVNite_1_5_0.so
```

Then i used strace to see where it looked for the library, and i got this

```
strace -e open ./Sample-SingleControl
open("/etc/ld.so.preload", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/local/lib/tls/v7l/neon/vfp/libOpenNI.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/tls/v7l/neon/libOpenNI.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/tls/v7l/vfp/libOpenNI.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/tls/v7l/libOpenNI.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/tls/neon/vfp/libOpenNI.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/tls/neon/libOpenNI.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/tls/vfp/libOpenNI.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/tls/libOpenNI.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/v7l/neon/vfp/libOpenNI.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/v7l/neon/libOpenNI.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/v7l/vfp/libOpenNI.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/v7l/libOpenNI.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/neon/vfp/libOpenNI.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/neon/libOpenNI.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/vfp/libOpenNI.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/libOpenNI.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/libOpenNI.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/local/lib/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/local/lib/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/v7l/neon/vfp/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/v7l/neon/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/v7l/vfp/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/v7l/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/neon/vfp/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/neon/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/vfp/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/v7l/neon/vfp/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/v7l/neon/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/v7l/vfp/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/v7l/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/neon/vfp/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/neon/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/vfp/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/v7l/neon/vfp/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/v7l/neon/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/v7l/vfp/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/v7l/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/neon/vfp/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/neon/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/vfp/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/v7l/neon/vfp/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/v7l/neon/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/v7l/vfp/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/v7l/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/neon/vfp/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/neon/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/vfp/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/tls/v7l/neon/vfp/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/tls/v7l/neon/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/tls/v7l/vfp/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/tls/v7l/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/tls/neon/vfp/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/tls/neon/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/tls/vfp/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/tls/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/v7l/neon/vfp/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/v7l/neon/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/v7l/vfp/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/v7l/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/neon/vfp/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/neon/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/vfp/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/tls/v7l/neon/vfp/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/tls/v7l/neon/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/tls/v7l/vfp/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/tls/v7l/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/tls/neon/vfp/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/tls/neon/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/tls/vfp/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/tls/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/v7l/neon/vfp/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/v7l/neon/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/v7l/vfp/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/v7l/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/neon/vfp/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/neon/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/vfp/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/libXnVNite_1_5_0.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
./Sample-SingleControl: error while loading shared libraries: libXnVNite_1_5_0.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory +++ exited with 127 +++
```

From what i can gather it seems to find the library, but then keep searching, i have also checked that the library is indeed in the right folder, and i have tried setting a path with ldconfig.

So how do i get it to find the library?

Comment: when you run file and ldd on that library, what do you get?

Comment: You are using a tutorial designed for a different OS on different hardware. Try looking for something which is designed for the Pi